# In Rails, why sqlite works without config.gem 'sqlite3-ruby'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

With a new Rails 2.3.10 project, the file `config/environment.rb` has the following line commented out:

```
# config.gem "sqlite3-ruby", :lib => "sqlite3"
```

but for some reason, I tried a scaffold `foo`, and start the rails server, and the app is running.

I thought the requirement is, every gem the app needs, it has to be listed in `config/environment.rb`?

Comment: But you have the adapter sqlite renseign in your database.yml ?

Comment: so if it is listed in database.yml, then no need to list in environment.rb?  In database.yml, it is `sqlite3`, while the gem is called `sqlite3-ruby` though...

Answer (score 1):

In Rails 2.3, it's enough to have the gem installed on your system for you to use it.

In Rails 3, you must have the gem listed in your Gemfile and installed via bundler to use the gem.

Comment: so all the `config.gem 'gem_name'` lines are really redundant?

Comment: actually, I kind of remember doing experiment of using `fastercsv` and needing to put `config.gem 'fastercsv'` into environment.rb

Comment: Not redundant, they need to be there for you to run rake gems:install. In your experiment adding it to env probably loaded fastercsv. You likely could have said "require 'fastercvs'"